# Why forEach if returns []?

Tags: reactjs, if-statement, foreach, react-hooks

I have an array with some orders, the name the array is getOrdersBySalesman. The orders have some attributes : id, client, stage. I want to filter the order by stage, but I it doesn't work, 
When I select for example "PENDENT" why the **console.log is []** I need to send the result of filterOrders to another component and I don't have result. What is wrong????

```
const Comandes = () => {
  const [orderStage, setOrderStage] = useState('')

  useEffect(() => {
    setOrderStage(orderStage)
  }, [orderStage])

  let filterOrders = []

  const filterStage = newStage => {
    getOrdersBySalesman.forEach(order => {
       if (order.stage === newStage) {
        filterOrders.push(order)
      }
    });
    setOrderStage(newStage)
  }
  console.log(filterOrders) = > IS []

  return (
    <div>
      <Layout>
        <select
          value={orderStage}
          onChange={e => filterStage(e.target.value)}
        >
          <option value="TOTS ELS ESTATS">TOTS ELS ESTATS</option>
          <option value="ACABADA">ACABADA</option>
          <option value="PENDENT">PENDENT</option>
          <option value="CANCELADA">CANCELADA</option>
        </select>
      {filterOrders.length === 0 ? (
          <p className="mt-5 text-center text-2xl">Encara no hi ha comandes </p>
        ) : (filterOrders.map(order => (
          <Order key={order.id} order={order} />
        ))
          )}
      </Layout>
    </div >
  )
}
export default Comandes
```

Comment: `filterOrders` will be changed on `onChange` event of `<select>` until then it's `[]` as you defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) won't return anything and it's just going to run on `select`, `onChange` event. So you should either wait for changing `select`. Also, for better performance, you should use [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`useState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) hook instead of declaring a variable and using `Array#forEach`.

So your final code should be something like this:

```js
const [filterOrders , setFilterOrders ] = useState([])

const filterStage = (newStage) => {
  setFilterOrders(getOrdersBySalesman.filter(
    (order) => order.stage === newStage
  ));
  setOrderStage(newStage);
};

useEffect(()=> {
  console.log(filterOrders);
}, [filterOrders]);
```

Comment: I doesn't work, when I select for example: "PENDENT" filterOrders return []. But If I put the console.log(filterOrders) after setOrderStage(newStage), I have results....:
setOrderStage(newStage);
console.log(filterOrders)
};

Comment: @ccnat First of all, it's better to use a `useState` hook instead of declaring a variable and then put your `console.log` on a `useEffect` hook. Second thing is, it could be vary on several things, if you provide a live demo using [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/) this could be more easier for us to tell you what the problem is. Check the update please.